# How to put a character as end of expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this regular expression

```
url\s*\((?:\'|"|)((\S*|\?)(?<!\'|\"))(?=\'\)|"\)|\))
```

It works well for what I want in these cases:

url("***../../Common/common/fonts/lato/lato-black-webfont.svg?#lato_blackregular***")

But when I have a situation like this it does not work the way I want it

lato_blackregular;src:url("***../../Common/common/fonts/lato/lato-black-webfont.eot");src:url("../../Common/common/fonts/lato/lato-black-webfont.eot?#iefix***")

How can I define ";" such as a line break, whenever you have a ";" it for the combination and start over?

**Demonstration of what is happening:**
https://regex101.com/r/2YHl2C/1/

Use `\S*?` does not work because it stops combining correctly with `background:url(/uploads/2019/03/0002-image(thumbnail_product).jpg)`

Comment: Change `\S*` to `\S*?`

Comment: It does not work for my case because it stops combining correctly with url (/ uploads / 2019/03/0002-image (thumbnail_product) .jpg)

Comment: Unmark as Duplicate

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/2YHl2C/2) correct?

Comment: No. He does not get /uploads/2019/03/0002-image(thumbnail_product).jpg

Comment: Can you please explain the requirements for the pattern? It is clear that you want to match from `url(`, then there may be an optional quote, then *some string* up to `)`. What can *some string* contain? Or, do you want to match up to `)` followed with `;` or whitepsace/end of string? Try `url\s*\(['"]?(.*?)['"]?\)(?![^;\s])`, see https://regex101.com/r/yzvxzM/1

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I want. Write as an answer and I mark as the solution of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
url\s*\(['"]?(.*?)['"]?\)(?![^;\s])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yzvxzM/1/).

The pattern will match substrings starting with `url(`, then there may be an optional single or double quotation mark, then will capture into Group 1 zero or more chars up to the first `)` followed with `;` or whitepsace/end of string.

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=url%5Cs*%5C(%5B'%22%5D%3F(.*%3F)%5B'%22%5D%3F%5C)(%3F!%5B%5E%3B%5Cs%5D)):

[image]

**Details**

- `url` - an `url` string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `['"]?` - 1 or 0 quotation marks
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `['"]?` - 1 or 0 quotation marks
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `(?![^;\s])` - there must be `;`, whitespace or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Why not use a recursive way?

Comment: @Jan It would not yield expected results.

Comment: See my answer, why not?

Comment: @Jan It won't extract the right string from `background:url(/uploads/2019/03/0002-imagethumbnail_product).jpg)`

Comment: True, bit that's not a valid string.

Comment: @Jan `background:url('/uploads/2019/03/0002-imagethumbnail_product).jpg')` and `background:url("/uploads/2019/03/0002-imagethumbnail_product).jpg")` are

Answer (score 1):

While you already have your answer, what about the imo cleaner (recursive) way:

```
url
(\(
    (?P<url>(?:[^()]*|(?1))+)
\))
```

This only needs a tenth of the steps needed by @Wiktor's expression (~4000 vs 400), see [**your modified demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2YHl2C/7/).

Comment: That sounds good too. The difference to @Wiktor is that his does not get the quotes. Which is the result I wanted. A group with only the url path